# Catalog URL Rewrite reindex issue after version upgrade

Tags: magento-1.6, ce-1.9.1.0, reindex

After upgrading `Magento 1.6 to 1.9.1` Catalog URL rewrite index mode is in running status,after that indexing is done from shell ,but `catalog_url is still in running mode`, due to this newly added products are redirecting to 404 not found page with `catalog/product/view/category/90/`. If anyone can give solution for it

Comment: check var/log if any exceptions show up

Comment: no exception generated for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved, by truncating `core_url_rewrite`.After that import backup file of table in Database and things will work fine with no reindexing issue.